# JQuery Calculate & Validate Total of Input Fields With Mod% Rules While Typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Please help I am trying to validate my input fields that accept 0 mod(%) of the following:

```
inputValue % 10 == 0;
inputValue % 20 == 0;
inputValue % 50 == 0;
inputValue % 100 == 0;
inputValue % 200 == 0;
```

The Above Inputs are not required but they should be at least one input data.

**Total**:
 
1) Should be auto calculated  and shows error on Tab or KeyUp if the value is not 0 @Mod of each field entered.

This field needs to be auto populated by triggered data of the amounts in the R 10, R 20, R 50, R 100, R 200

Here is the Form Below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //ar r10 = $("#r10_amount").val();

    $("#r10_amount,#r20_amount,#r50_amount,#r100_amount,#r200_amount").each(function () {

        $("input").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 9) {
                //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                var currid = $(this).attr('id');
                if (currid == "r10_amount" && (((this.value) % 10 == 0))) {
                    $('#r10_err').hide();
                    calculateSum();
                    //alert('inside');
                } else if (e.which == 9 && !isNaN(((this.value) % 10 == 0))){
                    $('#r10_err').show();
                    }

                if (currid == "r20_amount" && ((this.value) % 20 == 0)) {
                    $('#r20_err').hide();
                    calculateSum();
                }
                else if (e.which == 9 && !isNaN((this.value) % 20 == 0)) {
                    $('#r20_err').show();
                }
                //calculateSum();
            }
        //$(this).keyup(function () {

        //    alert($(this).attr('id')); 
        //    var currid = $(this).attr('id');
        //    if (((this.value) % 10 == 0) && currid=="r10_amount") {
        //        $("#r10_err").hide();
        //        calculateSum();
        //        $(this).focus(false);
        //    } else {
        //        $("#r10_err").show();
        //    }
        //    if (((this.value) % 20 == 0) && currid == "r20_amount") {
        //        $("#r10_err").hide();
        //        $("#r20_err").hide();
        //        calculatesum();
        //    } else {
        //        $("#r20_err").show();
        //    }
        //});
    });

});


});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("#r10_amount,#r20_amount,#r50_amount,#r100_amount,#r200_amount").each(function () {

        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#total").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>2. Capture Notes:</legend>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R10</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" name="r10" id="r10_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:red;display:none;" id="r10_err">Invalid Amount</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R20</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" name="r20" id="r20_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:red;display:none;" id="r20_err">Invalid Amount</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R50</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" name="r50" id="r50_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R100</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" name="r100" id="r100_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R200</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" name="r200" id="r200_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>Total</span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="total"><i class=""></i>0</span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You didn't tried anything?

Comment: Please see the attached above script @CalvinNunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an attribute `data` in every `input` where it have a modulus that should be used (e.g 10, 20, 50, etc...)

then I added a `keyup` listener to the inputs to check the values typed.
every time that is typed, it calculate the total in another function.

Check below code:

```js
$(".amnt").on("keyup", function(){
  let mod = parseInt($(this).data("mod"));
  let val = parseInt(this.value);
  
  if (this.value.trim().length < 1){
    this.className = "form-control amnt";       
  } else if (val % mod != 0){
    $(this).removeClass("correct")
    $(this).addClass("error");    
  } else{
    $(this).removeClass("error")
    $(this).addClass("correct");
  }
  
  
  CalculateTotal();
})

function CalculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  $(".amnt").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("correct")){
      total += parseInt(this.value);
    }
  })
  $("#total").text(total)
}
```

```css
.error{
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.correct{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>2. Capture Notes:</legend>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R10</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="10" id="r10_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:red;display:none;" id="r10_err">Invalid Amount</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R20</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="20" id="r20_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:red;display:none;" id="r20_err">Invalid Amount</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R50</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="50" id="r50_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R100</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="100" id="r100_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R200</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="200" id="r200_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>Total</span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="total"><i class=""></i>0</span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Works Perfect, Thank you for your swift response @CalvinNunes

Comment: But it is taking 102 , 205, 501,1001,2001

Comment: Editted. It was just that I forgot to remove the `error` or `correct` classes, now it is working nice

Comment: ,I am trying to set a rule that if any of the fields has wrong input, the Submit should be disabled. Can you kindly assist in that regard

Comment: Open another question with that issue