# JQuery Disable Submit if any of the textbox have a wrong input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi Please assist here I am trying to disable Submit button if any of the textbox has input error.

Please see the below link:
[Here is the Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751922/jquery-calculate-validate-total-of-input-fields-with-mod-rules-while-typing)

Comment: past here the code, at the cuestion

Comment: Basic HTML5 validation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `keyup` event, when you check the value of the input, add code so that if it's invalid, disbale the button, and if all fields valid (not only the current because maybe there is another invalid field), undisable the button. Like the following:

```js
$(".amnt").on("keyup", function() {
  let mod = parseInt($(this).data("mod"));
  let val = parseInt(this.value);
  
  if (this.value.trim().length < 1) {
    this.className = "form-control amnt";
    
    if (0 === $('.amnt').filter(function() {
          return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
        }).length) { // There aren't non-empty fields
      $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
      // For old jQuery versions:
      // $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  } else if (val % mod != 0){
    $(this).removeClass("correct")
    $(this).addClass("error");
    
    $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
    // For old jQuery versions:
    // $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("error")
    $(this).addClass("correct");
    
    if (0 === $('.amnt.error').length) { // There aren't fields with validation errors
      $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
      // For old jQuery versions:
      // $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', '');
    }
  }
  
  
  CalculateTotal();
})

function CalculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  $(".amnt").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("correct")){
      total += parseInt(this.value);
    }
  })
  $("#total").text(total)
}
```

```css
.error{
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.correct{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>2. Capture Notes:</legend>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R10</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="10" id="r10_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:red;display:none;" id="r10_err">Invalid Amount</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R20</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="20" id="r20_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:red;display:none;" id="r20_err">Invalid Amount</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R50</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="50" id="r50_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R100</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="100" id="r100_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>R200</span>
                    <input class="form-control amnt" type="text" data-mod="200" id="r200_amount" placeholder="R0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=""></i>Total</span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="total"><i class=""></i>0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitBtn" disabled><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: But now if I put only the first amount it does not enable the submit button

Comment: @sibonisozungu Because you didn't fill the others fields. Do you want to enable the users to leave empty fields?

Comment: Yes At least one field to be inputed @Chayim

Comment: Ok, it was fixed.